# What are the limits of capping ratios to [0-1]?

Tags: data-cleaning

I work with some financial ratios. By construction those variables should be between 0 and 1. However, for some reasons I end up with values <0 and >1. These reasons include :

- reporting problems (fat finger errors, unit problems...)
- discrepencies between databases
- discrepencies due to accounting reassessment

What would be the reasons for me to not cap my ratios to [0,1] ?

Comment: Are you confident that a value of 1.2 should in reality be a value of 1? Or is it just unreliable junk that can't be meaningfully used?

Comment: I am working with ratios like a/b where 0<a<b. For exemple b = total revenues and a = revenues in a geographical area. Philosophicaly we should always have 0<a<b. However, in practice, due to reasons mentionned above (mostly operationnal errors, but also accounting norms), we can get <0 and >1 values.

Comment: My question is whether you expect out-of-range values to actually represent the range limits - if you have accumulated rounding errors, for example, a value of 1.1 would likely be justified in capping at 1. But if someone types 1.1 instead of 0.1, capping that at 1 is a big error - you'd prefer to just throw out the out-of-range data rather than attempt to infer what it should have been. If a lot of these cases are operational and not numerical errors, I wouldn't expect a consistent relationship between the reported number and the true value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, you risk biasing the model by making the values 0 and 1 more likely than they actually are. This may or may not be a significant problem; really only cross-validation will tell you.

I would go ahead and try it, but compare your results to a different method of filling invalid values, like using the mean() of the valid values plus an extra feature flagging the samples that were invalid. Make sure you cross-validate using a hold out dataset that's been transformed in the same way; you can then select the method that results in the best results of the cross-validation process.